# How to fix it Cannot use `setFieldsValue`

Tags: antd

How to fix it

> Warning: Cannot use `setFieldsValue` until you use `getFieldDecorator` or `getFieldProps` to register it.

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue with react hooks. Following solution works for me.

```
props.form.getFieldDecorator('Amount', { initialValue: 'My Value' })
```

As I feel the reason is initialValue is not going to change after the first render, just like defaultValue.

Comment: What if my input fields are in a collapsed menu (not rendered unless I expand it) How do I set their values dynamically with setFieldsValue

Answer (score 1):

From the doc https://ant.design/components/form/#this.props.form.getFieldDecorator(id,-options):

> After wrapped by getFieldDecorator, value(or other property defined by valuePropName) onChange(or other property defined by trigger) props will be added to form controls，the flow of form data will be handled by Form [...]

So, without the registration of the form field with `getFieldDecorator`, you cannot use `setFieldsValue`.

You are setting a value to a field that doesn't exist inside the form.
First, you must register the field into the form with `getFieldDecorator` and then you can use the setter.

Maybe the getter-style method name it's a bit misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Using **antd@5.11.2**

If you want to register a field, but don't want to show it to the user, you should add the field to form like this:

```
<Form.Item name={"updated_at"} noStyle />
```

Then you can set the form value when another value change, like:

```
    <Form.Item label="Name" name={'user_name'}>
      <Input
        onChange={(e) => {
          form.setFieldsValue({
            updated_at: dayjs().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
          });
        }}
      />
    </Form.Item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `setFieldsValue` after `componentDidMount`,or use `initialValue` option.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `getFieldDecorator` before `setFieldsValue`

Answer (score 0):

Well, because you are not using the hook of `const [form] = Form.useForm()`

after that in From Component you can assign **form** in

```js
<Form
   form={form}
>
.....
</Form>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

in this case it will be fixed, I hope you find it useful.